# ASP.NET - Page.Form.Action/this.Form.Action not redirecting payment gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
this.Form.Action = "https://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp";
```

This is not redirecting to payment gateway directly. If I add this code within button click event it is working fine. I want auto redirecting. Could you please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

In your button handler code you should write
`Response.Redirect ("http://...");`

What you're doing now is setting of an URL wich will be hit when user clicks next time on the button.

Comment: Hi Max,  I dont use buttons here. It should auto redirect to another page.